What, exactly, is the total number of characters in C's "basic execution character set"?
The following pages on cppreference.com seem jointly inconsistent:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/charset


Basic character set is also known as basic source character set.
The basic execution character set contains all the members of the basic character set, plus the following characters:
U+0000    Null
U+0007    Bell
U+0008    Backspace
U+000A    Line feed (LF)
U+000D    Carriage return (CR)


https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model


A byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory. It is defined as a contiguous sequence of bits, large enough to hold any member of the basic execution character set (the 96 characters that are required to be single-byte). C supports bytes of sizes 8 bits and greater.


https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases


The source character set is a multibyte character set which includes the basic source character set as a single-byte subset, consisting of the following 96 characters: ...


... as long as all 96 characters from the basic source character set listed in phase 1 have single-byte representations

It's not logically possible for both basic execution character set (BECS) and basic source character set (BSCS) to have 96 characters and for BECS to contain all members of BSCS plus 5 control characters.

The latest C23 draft is here: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf
The latest draft of C17 is here: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf
The most relevant passages can be located by ctrl+f for the string "Both the basic source and basic execution character sets" in these pdf files.
I get the impression from reading these that the BECS is a proper superset of BSCS, just as stated on cppreference's charset page. But I hesitate to conclude, as I seem forced to do, that cppreference (which I find normally very reliable) is wrong both on the memory model page and on the translation phase page. So, what's going on?

It's not logically possible what is not logically possible? "Includes" does not mean "is equal". It is a minimum requirement.

All it is saying is that the source character set must be capable of representing the characters required to express a C program. (Both ASCII and EBCDIC satisfy the requirements.)

From the C23 draft N3096, there are 95 members of the basic character set, not including new-line. (The later draft N3219 may include 3 additional characters.1)
The basic execution character set includes the 95 characters of the basic character set, the null character, an alert character, a backspace character, a new-line character, and a carriage return character, bringing the total to 100.
The basic source character set includes the basic character set and the new-line character that is used to replace the end-of-line indicators in translation phase 1, bringing the total to 96.
The basic execution character set is a proper superset of the basic source character set (although the actual character codes may differ). The members of the basic character set and the new-line character are present in both, but the basic execution character set includes 4 characters that are not present in the basic source character set.
Regarding the pages on cppreference.com:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/charset

The "Code unit" columns show the ASCII character codes, but has nothing to do with the C standard. The horizontal tab character is listed as "Character tabulation", and the vertical tab character is listed as "Line tabulation".

The paragraph:

Basic character set is also known as basic source character set.

ignores the new-line character that becomes part of the basic source character set during translation phase 1.

The new-line character is listed as "Line feed (LF)" in the list of members of the basic execution character set. (In ASCII-based execution character sets, C's new-line character is usually (always?) mapped to ASCII LF.) The alert character is listed as "Bell".



https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model

The phrase:

the basic execution character set (the 96 characters that are required to be single-byte)

does not take into account the null, alert, backspace, and carriage-return characters, but does take into account the new-line character. (As of C23, the characters @, $, and ` characters are also required to have a single-byte encoding. They are extended characters, not part of the basic execution character set, but are required to be present.)



https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases

The description of the 96 characters of the basic source character set includes the new-line character that is used to replace the end-of-line indicators. (As of C23, the characters @, $, and ` characters are also required to have a single-byte encoding. They are extended characters, not part of the basic source character set, but are required to be present.)



After C231, indications are that the following version of the C standard, code name C2Y will include the @, $, and ` characters as part of the basic character set. This will increase the number of members of the basic character set to 98, the number of members of the basic source character set to 99 (including the new-line character that replaces end-of-line indicators in translation phase 1), and the number of members of the basic execution character set to 103. (It is possible that this has already happened in C23.1)

1 It seems highly likely that this change has made it into the latest C23 draft (N3219) but since it is not publically available (it is only downloadable as a password-protected zip file), I have not confirmed it. However, the C2Y draft (N3220) does have the change, and according to the editor's report N3221, the only change between N3219 and N3220 is an editorial change to a footnote in Annex K.

N3096 is not the latest draft but possible the last one that will go live in the C23 version and not the next C2x.
The draft N3220 (January 2024), says the following in 5.2.1:

A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist
in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string.
/--/
Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following members: the 26 uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet
A B C D E F G H I J K L M  
N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet
a b c d e f g h i j k l m  
n o p q r s t u v w x y z  

the 10 decimal digit
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  

the following 32 graphic characters
! " # % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / :  
; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~  
@ $ `  

the space character, and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and form feed.

1 (nul) + 26 + 26 + 10 + 32 + 4 (space characters) = 99
The previous draft said 29 graphic characters where the current draft says 32, so in the previous draft we'd end up with 96.
Regarding the previous C23 draft N3096 (April 2023), check out What are source and execution character sets? There the 3 new characters were listed in a separate sub-chapter 5.2.1.1, which has since then been remade into 5.2.2 and the characters was added to the above quoted table instead.
This is what happens when people treat drafts as the final document I guess. While the technical content was voted in 2 years ago, this still doesn't seem particularly settled editor-wise. So we just have to wait for C23 to be released
(...which could be any year now, at the pace ISO bureaucracy moves...)

The null character is not included in the source character set. Arguably, the new-line character is included in the source character set because it is introduced during translation phase 1, replacing the existing end-of-line indicators, so the total number of characters in the basic source character set is still 99 (as of N3096). The execution character set also requires single byte values for the null character and the '\a', '\b'. and '\r' constants.

@IanAbbott The question is about the execution character set. I wasn't sure how cppreference came up with the number 96 and this seemed the most likely reason. I'm not sure why the total amount matters to the OP though. There's also another part of this chapter saying: "In the basic execution character set,
there shall be control characters representing alert, backspace, carriage return, and new line." So that's 4 more.

I don't think N3220 is a working draft for C23. It is a working draft for the subsequent version of the standard, C2Y.

The latest C23 draft is N3219. I don't know if the three extra characters are included in the basic character set or if they are still extended characters. (The N3219 PDF is password protected.)

@IanAbbott Hmm okay. Well there's the official ISO site https://www.iso.org/standard/82075.html. It doesn't say which version that is, but from the bookmarks in the pdf I can tell it still got 5.2.1.1 so maybe that is N3096. We will see when C23 gets released proper. But I guess this answer could be incorrect then.

There is an editor's report N3221 containing a link to a document containing a list of the comments that were successfully applied to the C23 DIS. No mention of changes to C23 5.2.1 though.

That document I mentioned with the list of comments is also available as a PDF and is N3216.

@IanAbbott I changed the answer a bit since it might not be accurate after all.

C2Y is supposed to come out 2030 at the latest, so at least we have an upper bound on when C23 should be published. :-)

Hmm, the editor's report N3221 under "C2Y Specific Changes" mentions one minor editorial fix to a footnote in Annex K, and says "There are no other changes between the n3220 and n3219", so it looks like you were correct about the late changes to the C23 draft 5.2.1. There is no mention of it in the comment disposition documents N3131, N3148, N3191, and N3216.

"So we just have to wait for C23 to be released (...which could be any year now, at the pace ISO bureaucracy moves...)" ==> The final version would be paid, no? Looks like I'd have to work with the drafts.

Re: "C23 to be released (...which could be any year now", "C23 gets released proper": what's the issue with the (proper) release of C23?
